# Should I use Tasker or Locale?

Tags: settings, locale, tasker, automation

For general detecting circumstances and triggering actions, what are the advantages/disadvantages of Tasker and Locale?  Which one does the best job overall capability for improving the usefulness of a phone/device?

Categories of particular interest (in no particular order):

- "Recipe" power
- "Recipe" ease-of-creation
- Variety of circumstances that each app can detect
- Actions and configurations that can be triggered
- Backing up setup
- Sharing configuration

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way to compare these two apps:

Locale costs more.  But it is a lot more user friendly.  You just set up "situations" with triggers and actions. Then you prioritize the situations.  That's it.

Tasker costs less.  But it is a lot more customizable.  It's more like being given a scripting language.  There are TONS of options and choices and it can get really confusing if you don't know what you are doing.  It is not made for the average user.

I will say that anything Locale can do, Tasker can do it too.  It just isn't as quick and easy to set it up.

In regards to backing up, you can backup Tasker into script files.  Locale has no built in back up system.

Both of these applications are extendable to do practically anything because they support plugins.  Tasker supports Locale plugins too.

Also: personally, I use both of these apps.  I use locale for setting up common situations (disable sounds when asleep, adjust brightness/screen timeout when plugged in, go silent at work, etc.) and then Tasker for... well... tasks!  Such as plugging in my headphones I reduce my media volume to 50% (I've blared music accidentally way too many times) and displaying a menu of music apps.

Comment: Does Tasker use both conditions and actions from Locale plug-ins?

Answer (score 7):

I am the developer of Locale, and I wanted to make sure the most up to date information is available here:

- Locale does support backup and restore.  More information about this feature can be found on our website at http://feedback.twofortyfouram.com/forums/5655-locale-feedback/suggestions/74784-backup-settings-?ref=title
- We publish a Headphones Plug-in condition and a free Media Volume setting for Locale, giving Locale the ability to adjust media volume based on headphones being plugged-in/unplugged.

Comment: Does locale support 'and' conditions, like 'I am at home' and 'it is Sunday'?