# how to force the phone not to use wi-fi to upload video to youtube?

Tags: htc-desire, youtube

I do not have wi-fi at home and I want to upload video I took into my youtube account. I have generouse data plan so I don't have to use wi-fi to upload larger files like the application forces me.

I am on HTC Desire 2.1

Answer (score 3):

Use the [mobile YouTube interface](http://m.yahoo.com) instead of the YouTube app?

Comment: @Al Everett: I cannot find `upload` in the mobile interface. After switching to desktop the 'upload' button does nothing in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

Apps like [Tasker or Locale](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2032/should-i-use-tasker-or-locale) should be able to allow you to turn off WiFi based on what application is running.

See Also: [Useful or cool Tasker recipes](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/775/useful-or-cool-tasker-recipes)

Comment: How will that prevent YouTube from detecting there's no WiFi connection?

Comment: If the WiFi connection is turned off when the app starts up, there is no WiFi connection to be detected when the app is running. If there is no WiFi connection, WiFi cannot be used for uploading. Or for anything else.

Comment: As I understand the question, the problem isn't WiFi being used for uploading, it's YouTube refusing to use 3G.

Comment: yes @Matthew Read is right. I don't think that YouTube (site) is refusing to use 3G but HTC uploader (program/application) requires the upload to happen only through wireless. Although the video file is just little one.