# On Android can I write scripts (similar to Win .bat files) to combine several command line commands?

Tags: automation, command-line, scripts

On Windows, I can run two commands using a .bat file.
How can I achieve the same thing on Android

For example:

1. update my podcasts by calling pcastclient /updateALL
2. force sync of my pictures sugarsync /forceupdate

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Android's shell will support a limited amount of [Unix-style shell scripting](https://supportweb.cs.bham.ac.uk/documentation/tutorials/docsystem/build/tutorials/unixscripting/unixscripting.html). It specifically should have a shell at `/system/bin/sh` that you can use, however:

1. The shell provided with Android has a severely restricted set of commands available to it. If you want to do anything even remotely complex you'll need a [busybox install](https://market.android.com/details?id=stericson.busybox) (or another shell).
2. It's generally pretty rare for Android apps to provide any kind of command line interface or binaries. I very much doubt that Sugarsync, for example, allows you to perform a sync from the command line.

If you want a bit of a GUI you may want to look at something like [GScript](https://market.android.com/details?id=nl.rogro.GScriptLite&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm5sLnJvZ3JvLkdTY3JpcHRMaXRlIl0.).

Answer (score 6):

There are a few Android apps that are able to control other Android apps, and can chain several commands together using their GUI in a similar way to a script, they both have plugins to extend their support to many popular Android apps and functions.

[Tasker](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) and [Locale](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.twofortyfouram.locale) are probably the most famous of these (see here for [some comparison](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2032/)) but there are also other [similar (free) apps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3893/) that you could look at.